# Updating links to an already redirected URL

Tags: redirect, seo

What is the best method to update any links in a site to a URL that has changed?

**Example:**

A URL exists (URL A): *domain.com/good-product*

We now want that to be (URL B): *domain.com/amazing-product*

So I will add a 301 for 'URL A' to 'URL B'

**But**

There are a lot of links in articles which go to 'URL A'. Would it be preferable to manually update those so they go directly to 'URL B'. Or leave them as they are and let the 301 take care of it? Would it even make a difference?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

If you want the page to automatically move to the new page, you can use the following JS code;

```
document.addEventListener[‘DOMContentLoaded’, function() {
  window.open(“new_url”, “_self”)
}
```

However, I suggest adding some text to the previous page, explaining that the website has moved will be better. Redirecting to another page can confuse visitors.

Comment: Thanks but this is more of a question on SEO rather than how to technically achieve it.